# How to redirect a search query from a wordpress search bar to another website?

Tags: php, search, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website where i want to redirect my search from my wordpress site to another website and display the results of that search on that website , with the contents of that website

Comment: OK? What's the question?

Comment: i need a code to redirect or displays the results of multiple sites on my single site . can u do it ?

Comment: This isn't a "give me the code" sort of place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the standard WordPress search form, you could hook into the `get_search_form` filter, and change the `action` attribute for the form.  So something like:

```
add_filter('get_search_form', 'so_change_search_form_action', 10, 1);

function so_change_search_form_action($form) {
    return preg_replace('#action="[^"]*"#','action="http://www.example.com/search"',$form);
}
```

That's completely untested code, but hopefully it'll get you started (I assume you have code on the destination server to handle the request).

Comment: i also used a plugin called google custom search bar , bt the problem is it shows a lot of duplicacy and adds in it , so can i remove that ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I've never used that plugin. Unless you mean remove it completely, in which case you can deactivate it from the Plugins menu